# sed replacement dependent on surroundings

Tags: regex, sed

How do I do a sed replacement on a file containing things like
`f[3][2,3][4]` which should be replaced by `f[3][2,3]["string"][4]`. Of course the numbers could be different numbers and I want the same replacement to happen. Here we need to give full pattern, something like

```
f\[[0-9]*\]\[[0-9]*,[0-9]*\]
```

to pick out the right part but then I need the replacement to give the same numbers that where matched earlier (as well as attaching `["string"]`). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/\(f\[[0-9]*]\[[0-9]*,[0-9]*]\)\[\([0-9]*\)]/\1["string"][\2]/g'
```

Or

```
sed -E 's/(f\[[0-9]*]\[[0-9]*,[0-9]*])\[([0-9]*)]/\1["string"][\2]/g'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/voBo5G)

Basically, capture the first part from `f` to the third index, and capture the number in the third index, too. Then, reference these values with `\1` and `\2` placeholders from the RHS.

**Details**

- `(f\[[0-9]*]\[[0-9]*,[0-9]*])` (ERE, in BRE, the `(...)` must be escaped) - Group 1 matching `f[`, 0+ digits, `][`, 0+ digits, `,` and 0+ digits followed with `]`
- `\[` - a `[`
- `([0-9]*)` - Group 2: 0+ digits
- `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! I have one question about the "details" to be sure I understand. You are saying that (2nd and 4th point) I should only escape the opening square bracket and not the closing one?

Comment: @Kvothe A closing square bracket is not special.